# How do I install an R package from source?

Tags: r, install.packages, r-faq

A friend sent me along this great tutorial on [webscraping *The New York Times* with R](https://web.stanford.edu/~cengel/cgi-bin/anthrospace/scraping-new-york-times-articles-with-r). I would really love to try it. However, the first step is to install a package called [RJSONIO][2] from source.

I know R reasonably well, but I have no idea how to install a package from source.

I'm running macOS (OS X).

Comment: This is very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages

Comment: The edit queue is full for this question, but here is a link to that stanford.edu blog post that works: https://web.stanford.edu/~cengel/cgi-bin/anthrospace/scraping-new-york-times-articles-with-r (note the tilde)

Answer (score 613):

If you have the file locally, then use `install.packages()` and set the `repos=NULL`:

```
install.packages(path_to_file, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Where `path_to_file` would represent the full path and file name:

- On Windows it will look something like this: `"C:\\RJSONIO_0.2-3.tar.gz"`.
- On UNIX it will look like this: `"/home/blah/RJSONIO_0.2-3.tar.gz"`.

Comment: This also works if the `file_name_and_path` is the local source repository of an R package.

Answer (score 115):

Download the source package, open Terminal.app, navigate to the directory where you currently have the file, and then execute:

```
R CMD INSTALL RJSONIO_0.2-3.tar.gz
```

Do note that this will only succeed when either: a) the package does not need compilation or b) the needed system tools for compilation are present. See: *[R for Mac OS X](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/)*

Comment: I tried this and got an error:

Madjoro-MacBook-Pro:~ Madjoro$ R CMD INSTALL RJSONIO_0.2-3.tar.gz
Warning: invalid package ‘RJSONIO_0.2-3.tar.gz’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified

Comment: You have to specify the correct path to the .tar.gz file and the XCode tools (http://developer.apple.com/TOOLS/Xcode/) are required.

Comment: Is there a way to build the binary .zip from the source?

Comment: Found the solution, you need to use --binary option.

Comment: How many times have you come here because you typed install instead of INSTALL?

Answer (score 56):

You can install directly from the repository (note the `type="source"`):

```
install.packages("RJSONIO", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error:

* Installing *source* package ‘RJSONIO’ ...
** libs
** arch - i386
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RJSONIO’
RMate stopped at line 3
* Removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.9/Resources/library/RJSONIO’
The downloaded packages are in
 ‘/private/var/folders/Ey/EyzhYjoKESmsmsZ6K87PeU+++TI/-Tmp-/Rtmpe3C96p/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Warning message:
In install.packages("RJSONIO", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R",  :
  installation of package 'RJSONIO' had non-zero exit status

Comment: Do you have the developer tools installed? They come in the Mac OS X installation dvd. Since this package has C code you will need a compiler to install it from source.

Comment: I suspect I do not have the developer tools installed. Atleast, I don't remember installing them. Thanks!

Comment: If you are doing this on windows, you can get the developer tools from  http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/ ... make sure when installing you check the box that says to update your path (may be a bit hard to read .... just checked the unchecked box that comes up)

Answer (score 36):

A supplementarily handy (but trivial) tip  for installing older version of packages from source.

First, if you call "install.packages", it always installs the latest package from repo. If you want to install the older version of packages, say for compatibility, you can call install.packages("url_to_source", repo=NULL, type="source"). For example:

```
install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RNetLogo/RNetLogo_0.9-6.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
```

Without manually downloading packages to the local disk and switching to the command line or installing from local disk, I found it is very convenient and simplify the call (one-step).

Plus: you can use this trick with devtools library's dev_mode, in order to manage different versions of packages:

Reference: [doc devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools)

Answer (score 12):

[From CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/githubinstall/vignettes/githubinstall.html), you can install directly from a GitHub repository address. So if you want the package at `https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection`, using

```
library(devtools)
install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 9):

In addition, you can build the binary package using the `--binary` option.

```
R CMD build --binary RJSONIO_0.2-3.tar.gz
```

Comment: `R CMD build --binary` is deprecated; use `R CMD INSTALL --build` instead

Answer (score 2):

If you have source code you wrote yourself, downloaded (cloned) from GitHub, or otherwise copied or moved to your computer from some other source, a nice simple way to install the package/library is:

#### In R

It's as simple as:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install('path/to/package')
```

#### From terminal

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75530169/5783745), you can clone a GitHub repo and install it with:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
R -e "install.packages('devtools');devtools::install('path/to/package')"
```

Or if you already have devtools installed, you can skip that first bit and just clone the repo and run:

```
R -e "devtools::install('path/to/package')"
```

---

Note that if you're on ubuntu, install [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75531886/5783745) system libraries before installing devtools (or devtools won't install properly).

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev -y
```