# Installing a local package that's not a .tar.gz

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm working on a script that creates a package in the current directory (using pdInfoBuilder from BioConductor), and I'd like to install it while the script is running. `install.packages()` with repo=NULL seems like an obvious choice, but this seems to only except package directories tarballed and gzipped. Is there a way I can override this, since the `create.pkg()` function doesn't create a *.tar.gz? Currently I am using:

```
R CMD INSTALL package.name
```

Thanks,
Vince

Comment: Looking through the install.packages() code, all it seems to do is run R CMD INSTALL using a system() call in a user friendly way -

Comment: If it isn't a .tar.gz, what is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's a source file, then use install.packages() and set the repos=NULL:

```
install.packages(file_name_and_path, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

See this related question: [How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks Shane. I missed this in the documentation somehow.

Answer (score 3):

If it isn't a .tgz, is it in full directory form?  All you have to do is R CMD INSTALL dirname and it'll work.  The install.packages() function's only real advantage over a raw R CMD INSTALL is that it will do all the downloading, dependency matching, etc for you.