# How do I cross compile R packages for MacOS from a Linux environment?

Tags: linux, macos, r, cross-compiling

I'm running Linux and trying to compile an R package for use on a Mac. I could only find Linux->Windows and MacOS->Windows cross-compiling instructions. Does anybody know what I should do to compile a MacOS binary package for R?

Or, I'll settle for I build server. Again, there's a Windows build-server for R packages, but does anybody know of a MacOS build-server?

Comment: Depending on the details, you might consider setting up a project on http://rforge.net or http://r-forge.r-project.org , which incorporate build servers.  Maybe not feasible for a one-off cross-build.

Comment: The author of the R snpMatrix package apparently do that regularly.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/outmodedbonsai/files/
Consider asking him nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By first building a gcc crosscompiler -- see its documentation.

Available libraries may be a limiting factor, though. You'd have to rebuild everything from OS X you'd like to link against.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note:

While in R packages can be installed (from pre-compiled binary packages for all major platforms Windows, Mac, Linux) there are also tools for building packages from source as part of the installation process.

Example for installation from source ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474081/1144966)):

```
install.packages("Simpsons", type="source")
```

Depending on the package (pure R or with some other language like C/C++ in it) and depending on the OS you use, you need additional tools to build the packages from source (e.g. [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) for Windows, r-base-dev for Linux systems ...)