# How to build Mac OS binary from the source for an R package

Tags: r, macos, binary

I have the source code (X.tar.gz file) for an R package. How can I build the binary file for Mac OS of the source code file? My computer OS is linux.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cross-building in this way is not easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I cross compile R packages for MacOS from a Linux environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760609/how-do-i-cross-compile-r-packages-for-macos-from-a-linux-environment)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the reply. I think I will get a Mac computer to build it. In this case, is it enough to run: R CMD INSTALL x.tar.gz -build , or I need some prerequisites to install?

Comment: you need Xcode installed