# Is it possible to define the version of a package in R install.packages?

Tags: r

I know that you can download old packages and install them with

```
R CMD INSTALL package-version.tar.gz
```

I wonder if you can tell `install.packages()` to install a specific version from a repository, saving you from having to locate the tar.gz first. I have neither found this option in the help entry for install.packages nor googling for it. If this option does not exist, is there any reason for that?. I can only think that not all repos have all versions so you are forced to find the version first and download it.

There is an [equivalent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175414/install-old-package-using-install-packages) already in SO but the problem and answer is more about repository problems, so at the end they never answered this question directly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`install.packages()` does not, but there is a function `install_version()` in the `devtools` package which can install a version other than the most recent one from a CRAN repository.

Answer (score 1):

`remotes::install_version(package, version= version number, lib =location)` and `versions::install.dates(pkgs, dates, lib)` are two other options. Also, checkpoint will fix the R version too.

```
library(checkpoint)
checkpoint("2020-01-01", r_version="3.6.2")
```