# How to keep using R version 2.x and download packages automatically with install.packages() by package name?

Tags: r

My work setup relies heavily on rcom library, which is so far unavailable for R 3.x (due to licensing problems).

I'm happy to keep using the R v. 2.15.3, but the install.packages doesn't fetch new packages anymore.

Is there any way of making old R download packages on demand with something like `install.packages("MASS")`?

Comment: good question, but I think it will be hard/hackish.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670162/is-it-possible-to-define-the-version-of-a-package-in-r-install-packages?rq=1

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, although it helps a lot.  You'd still need to do some work to determine what archived versions existed/were compatible with your R version (i.e. you'll need to replace some of the functionality of `available.packages()`).

Comment: I don't suppose you saved your previous collection of `R` packages? If you happen to have some older versions of `R` on your machine, check the /library directory.

Comment: @Carl Yes, I know this trick. But it is very manual and obviously doesn't work for packages I only recently started using.

Comment: RDCOMClient works on R 3.0 and is very similar to rcom. Should not take much time to convert your code.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is the fallback solution:

We can always download (windows) old packages from this location on the [CRAN site](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/) and unpack the ZIPs into `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.3\library` or equivalent. But it would be cool to use some form of simple R command for doing it.

It is also possible to try using different mirrors, because mirrors are not equivalent with respect to volume of archives.

At least this is how I do it on (virtual) Windows XP 32 bit.