# Install previous version of a package from old source in windows

Tags: windows, r, installation, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

How can I use the .gz file provided in "Old sources" in order to create the .zip file R needs for local installation?

Comment: either install Rtools (probably the simpler thing) and build from source (so you don't need the zip) *or* untar; change the Maintainer e-mail in the DESCRIPTION field to your own; re-tar; and send the file off to the CRAN win-builder server (google for it) [not posting as a comment since I haven't gone to the trouble of finding any of the relevant links for you]

Comment: I was informed that the duplicate I was referring actually pertains MacOS, not Windows. A quick search for `how to build a package windows r` yields some useful results.

Comment: http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/Rintro/Rwinpack.html