# Which package can I use instead of package uroot?

Tags: r

I want to use function "bbaplot" and "bbplot" within package uroot, but I recognised there is no package called uroot. Which package can I use instead of this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: So do you want to use it or not? Package uroot exists. http://uroot.r-forge.r-project.org/

Comment: Googling for `R package uroot` leads to the link given by @sashkello.

Comment: [Here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uroot/) it shows the package has been removed.  I'm guessing it didn't pass CRAN checks for R 3.0.0 and the user is using 3.0.0.  This got a downvote but is actually a terrific question if rephrased.  Something like how to build an archived package on R 3.0.0.

Comment: @TylerRinker That's a long way from this question... :) I didn't downvote though, but the question certainly should be rephrased.

Comment: Agreed but I'm strongly encouraging the user to get this question there or it's doomed to be closed.

Comment: I cannot download it, because this package is terminated. I think, the function "bbaplot" and "bbplot" were probably put to somewhere else, e.g. to another package, but I do not know the name of the new package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Tyler Rinkers point that there is a [more general issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973594/how-to-build-an-archived-package-on-r-3-0-0/15973981#15973981) in question here is well taken.

@hadleys answer (from the above link) is concise.

The following (slower) solution also worked for me and avoids the need to install `devtools`.

Download the version of interest from [here](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/uroot/), e.g. `uroot_1.4-1.tar.gz` (the most recent).

In `R` use `setwd()` to make sure you're in the same directory as this file. 
(I like to copy and modify the output from `getwd()` to do this quickly).

Install as follows (borrowed from [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)):

```
install.packages("uroot_1.4-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Then make sure things are OK with:

```
require(uroot)
?bbaplot
```

My `sessionInfo()` output includes:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```