# How to build an archived package on R 3.0.0

Tags: r

Recently R 3.0.0 was rolled out.  [One of the requirements](http://mac.softpedia.com/progChangelog/R-for-Mac-OS-X-Changelog-16023.html) was that "*Packages need to be (re-)installed under this version (3.0.0) of R.*"

The problem occurs when you have packages that have been archived.  In an OS independent way how do you build packages like [uroot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uroot/)?  As you can see the package is archived.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to build a package from the archive is to use devtools:

```
library(devtools)
install_url("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/uroot/uroot_1.4.tar.gz")
```

There are three challenges:

- You need to have a working development environment. On windows, this means you need Rtools; on the mac, the xcode command line tools; and on linux, the appropriate development packages
- There is currently a bug in devtools which means it doesn't find the right version of Rtools on windows. A fix is on its way to CRAN.
- There's normally a good reason that a package has been put in the archive: it's likely that it does not pass `R CMD check` in the current version of R, so even once you've installed it, it might not work correctly. Be careful!

Comment: Quick note: for people behind a corporate firewall, download the archive and use `install` on the local copy.