# Flow chart using {diagram} in R 3.0.0 for Windows

Tags: r, error-handling, diagramming

I am trying to re-make a flow chart in R using the diagram package (v 1.6). I was able to make a chart using this exact script (which I modified from the example in the diagram documentation), but once I updated R to 3.0.0, the coordinates function gives me an error. Here is an example:

```
library(graphics)
library(diagram)

par(mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
openplotmat()
elpos<-coordinates(c(1,1,2,4))

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

I am still new to R and code, etc., so when I run traceback(), I really don't understand what it is telling me:

```
3: stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
   sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
2: (function (classes, fdef, mtable) 
  {
   methods <- .findInheritedMethods(classes, fdef, mtable)
   if (length(methods) == 1L) 
       return(methods[[1L]])
   else if (length(methods) == 0L) {
       cnames <- paste0("\"", sapply(classes, as.character), 
           "\"", collapse = ", ")
       stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
           sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
   }
   else stop("Internal error in finding inherited methods; didn't return a unique method", 
       domain = NA)
  })(list("numeric"), function (obj, ...) 
  standardGeneric("coordinates"), <environment>)
1: coordinates(c(1, 1, 2, 4))
```

Mostly I don't know why coordinates() won't work post-update. Any insight with that, as well as possibly a translation of the traceback would be a huge help. Thank you!

Comment: Did you rebuild the package from source? Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973594/how-to-build-an-archived-package-on-r-3-0-0

Comment: @TARehman  Why build?  The 3.0.0 binaries are on CRAN.  Just make sure you updated all your libraries, in particular `diagram`  and try again.

Comment: @TARehman, I have never tried rebuilding packages, but I uninstalled and reinstalled the diagram package (everything had been updated - I tried that first). Apparently coordinates() was being masked by a different package, so I tossed that and after the reinstall, everything works. Thank you so much for your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer the question so much as the problem. Initially, I could not reproduce your error:

```
library(diagram)
openplotmat()
(elpos1 <- diagram::coordinates(c(1,1,2,4)))
#       [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] 0.500 0.875
# [2,] 0.500 0.625
# ...
```

### Finding Same-Named Functions

However, looking for other instances of a `coordinates` function revealed something:

```
help.search('coordinates', fields='name')
# Help files with name matching 'coordinates' using fuzzy matching:
# 
# diagram::coordinates                  coordinates of elements on a plot
# sp::coordinates-methods               retrieve (or set) spatial coordinates
# sp::coordinates                       sets spatial coordinates to create spatial data, or retrieves spatial
#                                       coordinates
# sp::coordnames                        retrieve or assign coordinate names for classes in sp
```

This output searches all installed (not necessarily loaded) packages. From this, it appears that `sp` also has one. Using its version in your use-case produces the error.

### Package Loading Order (or, Masked Functions)

The order that packages are loaded is important, as functions from later-loaded functions mask functions of the same name from previous-loaded packages. Specifically:

```
# ensure we have neither package loaded
detach(package:diagram, unload=TRUE) # ignore errors if not loaded
detach(package:sp, unload=TRUE)      # ignore errors if not loaded
library(diagram)
library(sp)
# Attaching package: 'sp'
# 
# The following object is masked from 'package:diagram':
# 
#     coordinates
```

This message is telling you that a simple call to `coordinates()` will be using the version from `sp` and not from `diagram`. (For each code block below, I use `detach()` as above to ensure neither package nor its nameSpace is still around.)

Using the `sp` version produces the same error that you got, after having loaded the libraries in the order: `diagram`, `sp`:

```
library(diagram)
library(sp)
# Attaching package: 'sp'
# 
# The following object is masked from 'package:diagram':
# 
#     coordinates
(elpos <- coordinates(c(1,1,2,4)))
# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
# unable to find an inherited method for function 'coordinates' for signature '"numeric"'
```

The `traceback()` is identical to what you provided.

Reversing the loading order works:

```
library(sp)
library(diagram)
# Attaching package: 'diagram'
# 
# The following object is masked from 'package:sp':
# 
#     coordinates
(elpos <- coordinates(c(1,1,2,4)))
#       [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] 0.500 0.875
# [2,] 0.500 0.625
# ...
```

Note that the warning now tells you that `sp::coordinates()` is now masked.

### When In Doubt, Be Unambiguous

If there's any doubt as to which version is being called, we can always force which we intend to use:

```
(elpos <- diagram::coordinates(c(1,1,2,4)))
#       [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] 0.500 0.875
# [2,] 0.500 0.625
# ...
```

I feel a little off posting this as an *answer*, since I'm addressing your *problem* and not necessarily the stated *question*. Please keep prompting for answers if you still need to hunt down the results of `traceback()`. In that effort, though, I could not find `.findInheritedMethods()`, but it makes sense when `diagram::coordinates` is expecting a *vector specifying the number of elements in each row, or 2-columned matrix with element position, or 'NULL'*, while `sp::coordinates` is expecting *object deriving from class "Spatial"* (which is most definitely not a simple vector).

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is a really helpful explanation. And it answers the question just fine thanks. :)