# Reshape Data Frame from Long to Wide with Condensed Columns

Tags: r, reshape

Say I have (fake) patient data from their visits:

```
## Create a fake dataframe  
foo <- data.frame(PatientNumber=c(11,11,11,22,22,33,33,33,44,55,55), 
      VisitDate=c("11/03/07","11/03/07","11/20/07","12/20/08", 
      "12/30/09","09/20/12","09/20/12","10/25/07","05/09/08","06/09/13","06/09/13"), 
       ICD9=c(10,15,10,30,30,25,60,25,14,40,13))
```

Which gives:

```
   PatientNumber VisitDate ICD9
1             11  11/03/07   10
2             11  11/03/07   15
3             11  11/20/07   10
4             22  12/20/08   30
5             22  12/30/09   30
6             33  09/20/12   25
7             33  09/20/12   60
8             33  10/25/07   25
9             44  05/09/08   14
10            55  06/09/13   40
11            55  06/09/13   13
```

I would like to have a unique row for each patient at a given visit date. If the patient has multiple codes for a date, I would like a new column for all ICD code given at that visit. This is what it would look like:

```
WhatIWant <- data.frame(PatientNumber=c(11,11,22,22,33,33,44,55), 
                    VisitDate=c("11/03/07", "11/20/07", "12/20/08", "12/30/09", "09/20/12","10/25/07","05/09/08","06/09/13"), 
                    ICD9_1=c(10,10,30,30,25,25,14,40), 
                    ICD9_2= c(15,NA,NA,NA,60,NA,NA,13))




> WhatIWant
  PatientNumber VisitDate ICD9_1 ICD9_2
1            11  11/03/07     10     15
2            11  11/20/07     10     NA
3            22  12/20/08     30     NA
4            22  12/30/09     30     NA
5            33  09/20/12     25     60
6            33  10/25/07     25     NA
7            44  05/09/08     14     NA
8            55  06/09/13     40     13
```

I've tried reshape, but it seems to add all the ICD9 codes in a column and add the value in a column if they have a value or not (as shown below).I will end up with something like 200 columns, I would only like 3 (the max # of codes per patient per visit in the data set I have, ie ICD9_1, ICD9_2, ICD9_3).

```
test <- reshape(foo, idvar = c("VisitDate"), timevar = c("PatientNumber"), direction = "wide")

> test
    VisitDate ICD9.11 ICD9.22 ICD9.33 ICD9.44 ICD9.55
1  0007-11-03      10      NA      NA      NA      NA
3  0007-11-20      10      NA      NA      NA      NA
4  0008-12-20      NA      30      NA      NA      NA
5  0009-12-30      NA      30      NA      NA      NA
6  0012-09-20      NA      NA      25      NA      NA
8  0007-10-25      NA      NA      25      NA      NA
9  0008-05-09      NA      NA      NA      14      NA
10 0013-06-09      NA      NA      NA      NA      40
```

Sorry if the title isn't as specific as it could be, I'm not really sure how to exactly title what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem for `reshape` in this case is that it doesn't have a real "time" variable. That's easy to create with `ave`:

```
foo$time <- with(foo, ave(rep(1, nrow(foo)), 
                          PatientNumber, VisitDate, 
                          FUN = seq_along))
```

Then, you can use `reshape` as follows:

```
reshape(foo, direction = "wide", 
        idvar=c("PatientNumber", "VisitDate"), 
        timevar="time")
#    PatientNumber VisitDate ICD9.1 ICD9.2
# 1             11  11/03/07     10     15
# 3             11  11/20/07     10     NA
# 4             22  12/20/08     30     NA
# 5             22  12/30/09     30     NA
# 6             33  09/20/12     25     60
# 8             33  10/25/07     25     NA
# 9             44  05/09/08     14     NA
# 10            55  06/09/13     40     13
```

---

Of course, once you have that "time" variable, you can also use `dcast` from "reshape2".

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(foo, PatientNumber + VisitDate ~ time, value.var="ICD9")
```

Answer (score 7):

Also,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # See below on how to get tidyr

foo %>% 
  group_by(PatientNumber, VisitDate) %>%
  mutate(n=paste("ICD9",row_number(), sep="_")) %>%
  spread(n, ICD9)

 #Source: local data frame [8 x 4]

#  PatientNumber VisitDate ICD9_1 ICD9_2
#1            11  11/03/07     10     15
#2            11  11/20/07     10     NA
#3            22  12/20/08     30     NA
#4            22  12/30/09     30     NA
#5            33  09/20/12     25     60
#6            33  10/25/07     25     NA
#7            44  05/09/08     14     NA
#8            55  06/09/13     40     13
```

Package `tidyr` is not available on CRAN yet. Install it like this (see [`tidyr` git](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr)):

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
```

Comment: +1 for the excellent use of `n()` inside `mutate`!  I had no idea it would work outside of `summarise`!

Comment: I made a tiny edit, and changed `seq` to `seq_len`, just because it is faster and a bit more readable IMHO.

Comment: I copied/pasted "devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr") into R and it wouldn't download?

Comment: `AndrewMacDonald`: Thanks for the edit.  `James`:  Are you getting any error messages while downloading?  I am using R 3.1.0 on a linux platform.

Comment: Even better, you could use `row_number()`

Comment: It says "error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no packaged called 'devtools'. Mac Mavericks. RStudio v 0.98.953 @AndrewMacDonald

Comment: @James.  Seems like you have to install package 'devtools'. If you have errors in installing that package, please check this link. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923209/problems-installing-the-devtools-package>

Answer (score 2):

You could use `aggregate`:

```
max_visits = 2
aggregate(ICD9 ~ PatientNumber + VisitDate, foo, 
          function(x) x[seq_len(max_visits)])  #note that output is 3 columns
#  PatientNumber VisitDate ICD9.1 ICD9.2
#1            44  05/09/08     14     NA
#2            55  06/09/13     40     13
#3            33  09/20/12     25     60
#4            33  10/25/07     25     NA
#5            11  11/03/07     10     15
#6            11  11/20/07     10     NA
#7            22  12/20/08     30     NA
#8            22  12/30/09     30     NA
```

If you don't know the maximum possible visits ("max_visits"), you could:

```
max_visits = max(ave(foo[["ICD9"]], 
                     foo[["PatientNumber"]], foo[["VisitDate"]],
                     FUN = length))
max_visits
#[1] 2
```

**EDIT**:

As noted by @AnandaMahto in the comments you could turn your 3-column `aggregate`d "foo" (say "aggfoo") to 4 columns with something like:

```
dim(aggfoo)
#[1] 8 3
dim(do.call(data.frame, aggfoo))
#[1] 8 4
dim(data.frame(unclass(aggfoo)))
#[1] 8 4
```

That's not necessary, though, as even with 3 columns it's still convenient to call each "ICD9" column:
`aggfoo$ICD9[, 1]` and `aggfoo$ICD9[, 2]` instead of `aggfoo$ICD9.1` and `aggfoo$ICD9.2`.

Comment: +1. Interesting approach. I've posted a variant that uses `ave` + `reshape`.

Comment: Oh, and to "flatten" that output from `aggregate` and have four columns instead of three that look like four, you could wrap it in a `do.call(data.frame, ...)`.