# install devtools package in R

Tags: r, devtools

trying to install the devtools package in R I run into trouble

```
> install.packages("devtools",dependencies=TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/evandar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘BiocInstaller’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘httr’, ‘RCurl’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 196942 bytes (192 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 192 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RCurl_1.95-4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 870915 bytes (850 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 850 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_1.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 112272 bytes (109 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 109 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/evandar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘RCurl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/evandar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘RCurl’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/evandar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpbsrCjU/downloaded_packages’
```

I found this post here

[Problems installing the devtools package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923209/problems-installing-the-devtools-package)

and installed curl but that hasn't solved my problem as install.packages is till not working with the error message being the message displayed above. Can somebody maybe suggest how I can circumvent this problem or what I am doing wrong? I am runnign on R 3.1.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.

If i type curl-config from the comment I get

```
The program 'curl-config' can be found in the following packages:
 * libcurl4-gnutls-dev
 * libcurl4-nss-dev
 * libcurl4-openssl-dev
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

which probably means the problem is not the same as in the duplicate. I installed curl with

```
apt-get -y build-dep libcurl4-gnutls-dev
apt-get -y install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Comment: How did you install `curl`?

Comment: http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/BiocInstaller.html BiocInstaller might not be at cran, but you can get it from there

Comment: Type `curl-config` at the command line. If "not found" then you haven't installed the -dev package as detailed in the duplicate reference question.

Comment: if i type that I get The program 'curl-config' can be found in the following packages:
 * libcurl4-gnutls-dev
 * libcurl4-nss-dev
 * libcurl4-openssl-dev
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>