# Failed to install devtools in R 3.1.2

Tags: r, devtools

I was trying to install the devtools package in Rstudio by `install.packages("devtools")` but failed. The error messages are:

```
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Could not find libxml2. Please install libxml2-devel (rpm) or libxml2-dev (deb).
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/home/xwang/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/xml2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available for package ‘rversions’
* removing ‘/home/xwang/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rversions’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rversions’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rversions’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/xwang/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpYccDpT/downloaded_packages’
```

Looks like it has trouble finding `libxml-2.0`. Does anyone know an easy fix to this? I'm using R version 3.1.2.

Comment: Upgrade your version of R first.

Comment: A related question that other visitors may find useful: [Problems installing the devtools package](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20923209/320399)

Answer (score 12):

Eventually I fixed the problem by:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Then another problems popped up:

```
Error : object ‘curl_fetch_memory’ is not exported by 'namespace:curl'
```

which can be solved by installing the curl package:

```
install.packages("curl")
```

Comment: To install `curl`, I needed to run `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`; running `R version 3.2.1 RC (2015-06-10 r68509)` on Linux Mint 17 (built on Ubuntu Trusty)

Comment: R 3.2.3, Linux Mint 18.1, I still needed to do the `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update to the newest version of R (R version 3.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

It require some developer libraries (sources): `curl developer`, `xml2 developer` as dependecy.
so install it with the package repository (yum, dnf, apt-get) and retry to install the devtools package in R.