# There is no package called devtools in R even after installing devtools

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to follow this guide to get R as a usable language in jupyter notebook.

The first step is to run:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
```

But even after running this command, I still cannot execute the next step:

```
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
```

returning the error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
```

If you look at the comment section of the link I posted someone else seems to also have run into this problem.

Update:
Scott Richie suggested I rerun install.packages('devtools')
this returned:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpgBI8IU/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘gh’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I read up on related threads and was able to get devtools. but I ran into the problem:

```
> IRkernel::installspec()
Error in IRkernel::installspec() : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 1.
```

This other thread had exited with code 127 and none of the solution did not work in my case. : [jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056164/jupyter-client-has-to-be-installed-but-jupyter-kernelspec-version-exited-wit)

Comment: Did you check the output of your `install.packages()` command? There was probably an error somewhere. Check again running just `install.packages('devtools')`.

Comment: I just ran it again and i think you're right, this is the problem. im updating my post now with the error message.

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status in a powerpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114991/installation-of-package-devtools-had-non-zero-exit-status-in-a-powerpc)

Comment: Also potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923209/problems-installing-the-devtools-package

Comment: Im on the latest Lubuntu 18.10 AMD64

Answer (score 0):

One quick and simple solution I found is :

1. Open Anaconda Navigator
2. Open The environment you are working with.
3. Go to not installed and then search Dev tools, you should see "r-dev tools" select that.
4. Click Apply and you are done.