# Install/importing an R library from cloned repo

Tags: r

I have an R library cloned from a GitHub repo that I would like to modify. However, I've never built and imported a library in R from anything other than CRAN. How do I go about this?

Comment: While I was able to get a solution from the answers and comments below, I will just leave a quick summary here: 
`devtools::install('path_to_the_cloned_repo/')` -- that's it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you intend to modify the code before building, then `install_github()` will not work. You should clone the git repo to a directory on your machine, and then run:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
build("~/put/the/package/path/here")
```

If you are using RStudio, you can use the cloned and modified source to create your own package as described [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio).

Comment: Is the path to the .Rproject file? What file needs to be passed to build?

Comment: `devtools::build()` is an optional step, but `devtool::install()` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

@GregorThomas comment is so important that I feel it needs to be clarified.

After you build your pakacage, you still need to install it. running `devtools::build` returns the location of the `tar.gz` file that you need to install. You can therefore assign that to a variable and pass it to `devtools::install_local`.

The path that you pass to `devtools::build` should be whichever folder contains the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Note, if you want to fork/clone a repo and give your version its own name, you can change the `Package` value in the `DESCRIPTION` file and this new name is what you pass to `library()`

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
my_cloned_library_build = devtools::build("~/put/the/package/path/here")
devtools::install_local(my_cloned_library_build)
library(my_cloned_library)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it all from the command line, try this:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
R -e "install.packages('devtools');devtools::install('path/to/package')"
```

Just replace `path/to/package` with the path to your cloned package. Note if you're on Ubuntu, you might have to install [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75531886/5783745) system libraries first.