# Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’

Tags: r

Sorry for duplicate post. I saw similar type of problem here [Problems installing the devtools package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923209/problems-installing-the-devtools-package) . But I couldn't able to resolve my issue using the solution mentioned here. So created a new thread

I have installed devtools in my R studio, version 1.2.1335 running on Windows 10,using

```
install.packages('devtools')
```

Then I ran following command

```
devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
```

But I'm getting error message

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
```

I tried to install libcurl4-gnutls-dev to resolve the issue, as mentioned in referred stackoverflow post, using following command

```
install.packages('libcurl4-gnutls-dev')
```

But got the error message

```
package ‘libcurl4-gnutls-dev’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

Also I tried to run following command in my command prompt

```
apt-get -y build-dep libcurl4-gnutls-dev
apt-get -y install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

But got the error message

```
'apt-get' is not recognized as internal or external command
```

Can you suggest me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did `install.packages` produce any messages, warnings, or errors?

Comment: `apt-get` is specific to debian-based linux distros (including ubuntu and others); if you aren't on a debian-based distro, then you need to know the package-management command for your distro. What OS are you using?

Comment: R version 3.5.1? The version after that came out two years ago. R 4.x has been around sind April 2020. Have you considered installing a year 2020 version of R?

Comment: @r2evans it says "Windows 10" in the post.

Comment: `apt-get` is a linux thing, not a windows thing, so I felt the need to verify. The question in that comment was more of an after-thought rhetorical question, perhaps I could have been less "passive" about it, that was not intentional. An attempt to install `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`, either as an R package or as an OS package on windows, suggests that there is research being done on the errors but a misunderstanding of the OS-component of the equation. Ultimately, details about messages/warnings/errors may be the most telling, as I suspect there will be errors about dep packages such as `curl`.