# Installing custom packages in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I m totally new to R . I was initially working on R Studio installed on ubuntu .It was working fine and now I wanted to shift to windows as I am comfortable on it .I have R and R studio installed but now when I try to install all those custom packages that was earlier available on ubuntu by :

```
install.packages('package-name');
```

it returns:

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ashique/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘package-name’ is not available (for R version 3.0.3)

Even when I try to install bigmemory I get the same error .

Please Help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the `bigmemory` package is unavailable for Windows:
[CRAN ReadMe - bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/r-release/ReadMe)

To install packages manually:
From a directory:
`install.packages(file_name_and_path, repos = NULL, type="source")`

From url:
`install.packages("bigmemory", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")`

See also:
[How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

Comment: I get the following error                                                      Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ashique/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependency 'bigmemory' is not available for package 'packagename'
* removing 'C:/Users/Ashique/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/packagename'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Ashique\Documents\R\win-library\3.0" "Ralgotree/"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘packagename/’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: You don't need to specify the installation location but the source location of your file.

Comment: Dont know if I am right but the mentioned the package as a zip file and hope the package was installed . How do I check if it was properly installed .Sorry I m new to R

Comment: NO ...the state is same . It kinda says that there is a bigmemory dependency. How to solve ??

Comment: I have not specified the installation location .Please help