# Building R igraph package in Win7

Tags: r, igraph

I made a small change to the source code of the `igraph` package because I want to implement the forest fire method based on the [breadth first search method](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/graph.bfs.html).

I used [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to build the package and followed the steps as this [link](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/building-r-packages-for-windows/). But, I got a error message:

```
foreign-graphml.c:38:29: fatal error: libxml/encoding.h: No such file or directory.
```

I  tested using the source code, but still had the same error.

I also used the [install.packages()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source) method. It still showed the same error.

Update:
I downloaded the Libxml2 and set the bin location to the path. The libxml/encoding.h file is actually in the 'include' folder. Why does this error show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build it at http://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx, just don't forget to change the `DESCRIPTION` file to include your email address as maintainer.

It is actually quite tricky to build it because Rtools has some fixed (?) paths and it is looking for libraries at specific places, so you need to put them there. We build it with something like

```
...
if ! (subst | grep -qi ^d:); then
  subst d: c:\\
fi

pkg=`ls igraph*.tar.gz`
zip=`echo $pkg | sed 's/.tar.gz/.zip/'`
rfile="r-win/${zip}"

OLDPATH=$PATH
PATH=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/R/R-default/bin:/cygdrive/c/Rtools/bin:/cygdrive/c/Rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin:$PATH

LIB_XML=c:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local R CMD INSTALL -l . $pkg
zip -r ${zip} igraph
PATH=$OLDPATH
...
```

This uses a cygwin shell. You can get the extra libraries here:
http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/libs.html

Comment: Thank you @Gabor Csardi. I actually read the web page at http://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx . But as it said, 'Prepare your source package (using R CMD build)'. I did not build the package successfully.

Comment: Your link that you followed is five years old, and outdated. Just do `R CMD build <dir>` to build your package. This will be a *source* package that you can upload to win-builder to get a *binary* package.