# Having trouble installing an older R package

Tags: r, package, igraph

I'm running Windows 7, have R version 3.2.4 Revised, and downloaded RTools. When I attempt to install an older version of igraph (0.7.1), I get the following error:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'igraph'
* removing 'C:/Users/Tom/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/igraph'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/igraph_0.7.1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/igraph_0.7.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The specific command I'm using is:

```
install.packages("C:/igraph_0.7.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

although I've tried this a number of different ways (in the command prompt, running as an administrator, using devtools), and nothing works. Any thoughts would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed another item a bit higher that might be a clue:    foreign-graphml.c:38:29: fatal error: libxml/encoding.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: Double post with this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624216/building-r-igraph-package-in-win7)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, but I'm still quite new to R, so it's tough for me to follow. Is there a more straightforward explanation somewhere, or other material I could use to figure this out?

Comment: What part is confusing? Just change the `DESCRIPTION` file to include yourself as the sole maintainer, upload the file and receive a binary in your email? See the [procedure instructions](http://win-builder.r-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a sufficiently recent version that you can install a built Windows binary of igraph from the MRAN "Time Machine" server. [Here's a direct link to the package](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-05-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/igraph_0.7.1.zip), which you can install using:

```
u <- "https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-05-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/igraph_0.7.1.zip"
install.packages(u, type = "win.binary", repos = NULL)
```

Comment: We Toms gotta look out for each other. Thanks, brother.