# Package installation version error in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to install CRAN packages after downloading and unzipping the source files in linux. The packages need to install some dependencies but I got following error, why is this so?

```
> install.packages("/home/sarah/lubridate", dependencies=TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/sarah/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘/home/sarah/lubridate’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

P.S I am connecting to the server through SSH and am a sudoer user. I did not use R CMD INSTALL as it needed to install some dependencies as well. 
Thanks

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `install.packages` help file:

> pkgs:     character vector of the names of packages whose current
>             versions should be downloaded from the repositories.
>
> ```
>       If ‘repos = NULL’, a character vector of file paths of
>       ‘.tar.gz’ files.  These can be source archives or binary
>       package archive files (as created by ‘R CMD build --binary’).
>       On a CRAN build of R for OS X these can be ‘.tgz’ files
>       containing binary package archives.  Tilde-expansion will be
>       done on the file paths.
> ```

So if you want to install from local copies of the libraries it seems you need `repos = NULL`. I am not clear why you can't use a remote repository in the usual way.