# Installing text mining package in R on Linux

Tags: r, linux-mint

I am using R version(3.0.1) on Linux Mint 16
When I tried downloading the tm package using

```
install.packages("tm")
```

it gives me an error saying:

```
package ‘tm’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

How can I possibly fix this?

Comment: P.S.-there are answers for ubuntu systems but they are too old

Comment: `install.packages('tm', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`; does that help?

Comment: Download a version that is for 3.0.1 or older and compile it by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cran page `http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html` says : R (≥ 3.1.0).

Answer (score 1):

Download the applicable old version [here](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tm/) and then install from source:

```
install.packages(file_name_and_path, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

Comment: While there are many files out there, is there a way to know which file matches the version of R I have?