# install cnv-seq.tar.gz in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install this cnv-seq package on my R library to help copying number variation analysis. However, when I type in

```
install.packages("cnv-seq")
```

in R command, an error code pops out saying it is not available for 3.1.1 version. So I tried the old versions as well. All says not available. And I double check with the menu, Packages-> Install packages->. No cnv-seq

Ok. Then I tried to install it from a local source which is the "cnv-seq.tar.gz"

when i type in

```
install.packages("C:/cnv-seq.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

it still returns an error that says cannot extract package from this file.
Installation of package had non-zero exit status.

Anything went wrong or is there another I can install this package manually to my PC? After take a look at a similar question here couple years ago,

[How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

I still could not fix this problem.

Comment: Where did you get the file from?

Comment: @jbaums forget to mention that. my bad. You can access the file from http://tiger.dbs.nus.edu.sg/cnv-seq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of [RTFM](http://tiger.dbs.nus.edu.sg/cnv-seq/doc/manual.pdf) ;)

You can do the whole process from within R. Below, we download the archive to the temporary directory, then extract it and finally install it.

```
download.file('http://tiger.dbs.nus.edu.sg/cnv-seq/cnv-seq.tar.gz', 
              f <- tempfile())
untar(f, exdir=tempdir())
install.packages(file.path(tempdir(), 'cnv-seq', 'cnv'), type='source', repos=NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you first must untar the file. I believe 7zip has this capability if you do not have access to a linux machine. The linux command would be:

```
tar -xvf  /path/to/file/cnv-seq.tar.gz
```

After you do this you should be able to import the package into R.

Comment: Yep, this works fine (and yes, 7zip can extract the archive).

Comment: @jbaums i don't have trouble extract the files but import the package into R. :(

Comment: @jbaums just fix the problem. Thanks! :D