# Installing R package rpy2 from source in Mac OSX yosemite

Tags: r, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to install R package rpy2 on a new iMac running OSX Yosemite 10.10.1 and having problems. I downloaded a .tar.gz file and got a non zero exit status error message when I tried to install it in R:

> install.packages("/Users/SarahiMac/Downloads/rpy2-2.5.4.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
>   ERROR: cannot extract package from ‘/Users/SarahiMac/Downloads/rpy2-2.5.4.tar.gz’
>   Warning message:
>   In install.packages("/Users/SarahiMac/Downloads/rpy2-2.5.4.tar.gz",  :
>     installation of package ‘/Users/SarahiMac/Downloads/rpy2-2.5.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Per [this post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-packages-from-source-on-mac-os-x/), I installed Xcode (6.1.1) and tried to install the package in the terminal as follows:

```
R CMD INSTALL rpy2-2.5.4.tar.gz
```

And got following error message:

```
ERROR: cannot extract package from ‘rpy2-2.5.4.tar.gz’
```

I also tried to install with R CMD INSTALL --build per one of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source) and got the same error, and I converted the tar.gz file to a zip file and that didn't work either

Any thoughts?  Apologies if I am making an obvious error - I am a novice programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read things more carefully.  `rpy2` is a **python** package to talk to `R`,  not an `R` package.

Perhaps you want either `rPython` or `rJython` , available at CRAN.