# Can't install any packages in R

Tags: r, swirl

Title says the core of it. I've been wanting to learn R and I thought that swirl sounded nice. I can't get swirl to install, so just as an experiment I tried another package. I get the same error message. I'm getting this in both R and R Studio.

My input and error message are here:

```
install.packages("swirl")
## package ‘swirl’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
## Warning message:
## package ‘swirl’ is not available (for R Under development)
```

The first time I tried it I did get to chose a CRAN mirror, but otherwise I've been just spinning my gears.

I'm on a Mac and running OS X Yosemite, I tried looking for any issues similar to this and I am stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your R version?

Comment: Install as `source`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1474125/1000343

Comment: If you can't follow @Jeff's guidance, then you'll have to do what @Tyler suggests and use `type='source'` for (most) package installs.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using a bleeding edge version of R ("R Under development").

Downgrade to the latest stable version and you should be fine.