# R: install.packages() doesn't work nor produce an error message

Tags: r

I am running R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) with RStudio 0.98.1103 under OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite). I migrated to this machine recently and moved files and applications (R and profile files included) with OS X `Migration assistant`.

R has worked perfectly until I tried to `install.packages()`. The function initiates but it doesn't produce any printout or terminate. I tried different things:

- I removed my `.Rprofile` file which indicates my package folder and restart R;
- I tried different mirrors with `install.packages('RMySQL', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`;
- I tried `install.packages()` both from shell and from R GUI;
- I tried to upgrade all packages with RStudio.

I never encountered an error message of sort and none of the above worked or produced any result.

Comment: `install.packages()` is part of the `R.utils` package. Maybe it is corrupted? Try to install it manually from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.utils/index.html

Comment: @Molx How do you installa manually without install.packages()?

Comment: I think you can use `R CMD INSTALL --binary R.utils_2.0.0.tar.gz ` from Terminal, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source

Comment: @Molx I think you're wrong about that: there's an `installPackages()` function in the `R.utils` package, but `install.packages()` is part of the `utils` package that is built into R.  But unfortunately I don't have any guesses about what's wrong.

Comment: @BenBolker, Indeed. But maybe the alternative `installPackages()` could be used to reinstall `utils`? I have no idea if that would work though, even if `utils` is the issue.

Comment: You might describe how you have MySQL installed. The DESCRIPTION file says "MySQL/MariaDB client headers and libraries" are needed. I also see this note at CRAN Package Check Results: "Result: NOTE 
     installed size is 5.6Mb
     sub-directories of 1Mb or more:
     libs 5.3Mb ", so you may just need to be more patient?

Comment: I don't think `utils` can be reinstalled, it's a core package.  If things are that badly messed up (I can't tell), re-installing R itself would be way forward.  (It's easy enough that it might be worth trying anyway.)