# How to install a package from a download zip file

Tags: r

I have download this [package](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) as a zip file.

Is it possible to install it from R console using this zip or unzip version to a specific path?

```
install.packages("C:/Users/Desktop/rvest-master.zip', lib='C:/R/R-3.2.1',repos = NULL)
```

I type the previous command but is not working

```
> setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/")
> unzip("rvest-master.zip")
> file.rename("rvest-master", "rvest")
[1] TRUE
> shell("R CMD build rvest")
Warning messages:
1: running command ' /c R CMD build rvest' had status 127 
2: In shell("R CMD build rvest") :
  'R CMD build rvest' execution failed with error code 127
> install.packages("rvest_0.2.0.9000.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: invalid package 'rvest_0.2.0.9000.tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/R/R-3.2.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "rvest_0.2.0.9000.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("rvest_0.2.0.9000.tar.gz", repos = NULL) :
  installation of package ‘rvest_0.2.0.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

In the previous line are the results from the answer

Comment: Possible repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source

Comment: What does "is not working" mean exactly? Did you get an error message?

Comment: @cr1msonB1ade please could you advice me what I am doing wrong in the command?

Comment: I would first fix your quotation marks (first one is double second is single) and second I would try adding `type='source'`. What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Why aren't you following the install directions at that linked website?

Comment: @cr1msonB1ade it works but when I type library(rvest) it gives Error in library(rvest) : there is no package called ‘rvest’ Is there any way to find where the R package from installation process go and installed?

Comment: I guess your installed package is in the temporary directory and not R package directory. One way is to copy the folder from that directory to R package directory.

Comment: @user227710 and how can I find the R package directory?

Comment: Mine is `C:\Users\myname\Documents\R\win-library` and I am using Windows 8.

Comment: The `shell()` command doesn't work because R is not on your system search path. You can check this within R by typing `Sys.getenv("PATH")` and seeing whether your R directory is included. If not, you need to add it ([instructions](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)) and then restart R.

Answer (score 50):

You have downloaded a zip of the source of a package. This is not the standard packaging of a package source nor is it a standard Windows binary (i.e., a built package distributed as a .zip, as from CRAN).

The easiest thing for you to do is to install this package directly from Github using devtools:

```
library("devtools")
install_github("hadley/rvest")
```

If you decide to install it locally, you need to unzip the package directory, build it from the command line using `R CMD build rvest` and then install either using `R CMD INSTALL` or from within R using the command you already have (but performed on the built "tarball"). Here's how you could do all of this from within R:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/")
unzip("rvest-master.zip")
file.rename("rvest-master", "rvest")
shell("R CMD build rvest")
```

This will make a tarball version of the package in the current directory. You can then install that with

```
install.packages("rvest_0.2.0.9000.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```

Since the version number is merged into the tarball name, it may not always be obvious what the new file might be called. You can use `list.files()` to grab the new tarball.

```
install.packages(list.files(pattern="rvest*.tar.gz"), repos = NULL)
```

If the `shell()` line gives you an error like this

> 'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command

You need to make sure that R is in your shell path. You can add it with something like

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(R.home("bin"), Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
```

Answer (score 26):

Try `install.packages('C:/Users/Desktop/rvest-master.zip', repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")`. (Untested)

Comment: works great. also you can just copy link address directly from cran.  Here is an example. ```install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/proxy_0.4-20.zip', repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")```

Comment: I highly doubt this works great. The OP downloaded a githb repo zip, this is for win binary package, only CRAN host this kind of file.

Answer (score 9):

Hard to believe this don't have a clear, simple and accurate answer.

1. The zip you downloaded from github by clicking "download as zip" is a pack of that repo, which is not the standard R source package format like CRAN hosted. Thus the methods that work with CRAN source tar.gz will not work with this kind of zip.
2. The simplest method is to use `devtools::install_local`. If devtools bring too many dependencies to you, you can use `remotes::install_local` which is the real function and have much less dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the zip of the source of a package, and the R core `install.packages()` doesn't work, then you can use `install_local()` from the `devtools` package.

I often do this when installing packages from GitHub as getting curl through our proxy is painful. So I download the source zip and install like this.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 and R 3.5.3 I had to extract the zip, repackage it as .tar.gz and then install it using the command below. When installing the zip the package will not be indexed by R.

```
install.packages("C:/your-package.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary", lib="C:/Users/username/Documents/R/R-3.5.3/library")
```

Environment

> version
>                      _
>       platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>       arch           x86_64
>       os             mingw32
>       system         x86_64, mingw32
>       status
>       major          3
>       minor          5.3
>       year           2019
>       month          03
>       day            11
>       svn rev        76217
>       language       R
>       version.string R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
>       nickname       Great Truth

Answer (score -1):

Download the package.tar.gz

Then from command line :

```
R CMD INSTALL package.tar.gz
```

Comment: but the OP wants to install from a zip, not a tar.gz

Comment: tar.gz is the default to install R packages.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of install_local method in devtools package. Unzip the zipped file and specify the folder which contains DESCRIPTION file of the package in the path argument or you can also make use of subdir argument.

If it doesn't explains, I will post an example... Let me know.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it helps the OP, including an example would greatly improve this answer.