# Error while trying to install clusplus package

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install clusplus package (https://github.com/pablo14/coord_plot_usage)
offline using the command

```
install.packages("C:/Users/SJ/Downloads/coord_plot_usage-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/SJ/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’ (as
>   ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname,
>   "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :   cannot open compressed file
>   'coord_plot_usage-master/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file
>   or directory' Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"),
>   c("Package", "Type")) :    cannot open the connection Warning in
>   install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "C:\Users\SJ\Documents\R\win-library\3.3"
>   "C:/Users/SJ/Downloads/coord_plot_usage-master.zip"' had status 1
>   Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘C:/Users/SJ/Downloads/coord_plot_usage-master.zip’ had non-zero exit
>   status

I changed the type to "win.binary" from "source" but still it was not successful.

```
install.packages("C:/Users/SJ/Downloads/coord_plot_usage-master.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

> Installing package into
>   ‘C:/Users/SJ/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   cannot open compressed
>   file 'coord_plot_usage-master/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such
>   file or directory' Error in install.packages : cannot open the
>   connection

Since I am behind the firewall, I tried to change the config as below

```
set_config(use_proxy(url="http://----.com/proxy.pac", port=80))
install_github("pablo14/clusplus")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Tried to install it by following the steps in [How to install a package from a download zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989027/how-to-install-a-package-from-a-download-zip-file) but was not successful. Got the message

> Error in install.packages : zip file ‘coord_plot_usage-master.zip’ not
>   found

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a package from a download zip file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989027/how-to-install-a-package-from-a-download-zip-file)

Comment: are you sure the proxy port is 80 and not 8080? and you should be using the download from here https://github.com/pablo14/clusplus not coord_plot_usage. the latter is an example usage of the `clusplus` packages