# randomForest library zip file

Tags: random-forest

I work for a government agency so I can't directly download R packages because we are behind a firewall. I  asked the help desk for permission to download download the randomForest library. They let me download the zip file. But where do I save it so I can access it through RStudio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a package from a download zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989027/how-to-install-a-package-from-a-download-zip-file)

Comment: Just poke around here on the site and you will find other similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

So after poking around in RStudio, click on Tools->Install Packages then use the browse option to point to the saved file and it will import it.