# RDCOMClient for R 3.6

Tags: r

I have downloaded the package from
https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient

and followed the directions to install it from local source from

[How to install a package from a download zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989027/how-to-install-a-package-from-a-download-zip-file)

However, I still get the following error:
*Warning in install.packages:
  package 'RDCOMClient_0.94-tar.gz' is not available (for R version 3.6.0)*

Is it possible to install RDCOMClient on R 3.6.0?  If so, how?

Answer (score 7):

Use the package for version 3.5, it works without problems:

```
url <- "http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.5.1/RDCOMClient_0.93-0.zip"
install.packages(url, repos=NULL, type="binary")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install from Github using devtools (v.0.94-0) to R 3.6.

```
devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient");
```