# Sending R Markdown output as body email via outlook (RDCOMclient) - R version 3.6.1

Tags: r, r-markdown, rdcomclient

I use this exact code ([Sending R Markdown output as body email via outlook (RDCOMclient)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237343/sending-r-markdown-output-as-body-email-via-outlook-rdcomclient)) and it worked just fine, until I update my version of R to 3.6.1.

I also tried the 3.5 version of RDCOMClient as explained here ([RDCOMClient for R 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638636/rdcomclient-for-r-3-6)) and I still got NA as body of my mail...

Anyone knows how to fix this??

Edit: (line of code)

```
knitr::knit("tale_email_body.Rmd", encoding = "UTF-8")  
eb <- read_lines("tale_email_body.html",locale =  locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))     
Encoding(eb)

eb2 <- paste(eb, sep="", collapse="")
eb2 <- iconv(eb2, from = "UTF-8",to= "Latin1")


library(RDCOMClient)

olMailItem <- 0
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(olMailItem)

# this retains default Outlook signature
outMail$GetInspector()
signature <- outMail[["HTMLBody"]]

outMail[["To"]] <- sm
outMail[["CC"]] <- paste("egrp",dm,sep=";")
outMail[["subject"]] <- "note this"
outMail[["BodyFormat"]] <- 2
outMail[["HTMLbody"]] <- paste0(eb2, signature)
outMail$Display()
outMail$Send()
```

Comment: It's not clear what the link to the code means - it's another question with a couple of answers.

Comment: I just edit to add the code.

Comment: Did you update all the packages used and Rstudio? (I haven't done anything with rdcomclient, so that's all I can think of.)

Comment: Yes, I update all the package. I use Rstudio and even update it juste in case....I still got NA as body of my mail...

Comment: This looks relevant: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rdcomclient-is-not-available-for-r-version-3-6-1/35914/6

Comment: Thanks for your help! I installed the version form Dkyleward, but I had also an encoding problem. So when I add: `sub="byte"`it all work.

Comment: Could you provide the content of your RMD file? That would be useful to replicate what you did.