# Installing a source package in R, getting errors

Tags: r, install.packages

I was/am trying to install some packages and keep getting errors.

at first I was trying the "Install packages" from the tools menu as I always do, and got the error

> install.packages("partykit")
>   Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
>     ‘partykit’
>     These will not be installed

Which brought me to suggestions like this:
[How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

so I tried downloading package and this code, no idea what I am doing wrong, any help?:

```
install.packages("C:\\Users\\sandera\\Downloads\\partykit_1.0-4.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
> install.packages("C:\\Users\\sandera\\Downloads\\partykit_1.0-4.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
* installing *source* package 'partykit' ...
** package 'partykit' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/Users/sandera/DOCUME~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/sandera/DOCUME~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="partykit.dll" OBJECTS="ctreecall.o ctreelinstat.o ctreesplit.o ctreeteststat.o ctreeutils.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'partykit'
* removing 'C:/Users/sandera/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/library/partykit'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/Users/sandera/DOCUME~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\sandera\Documents\R\R-3.2.2\library" "C:/Users/sandera/Downloads/partykit_1.0-4.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/sandera/Downloads/partykit_1.0-4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: The package has windows binary as we can see here https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/partykit_1.0-4.zip. Install that and it'll do. Maybe you need to fix your repos.

Comment: Hmm, well i feel dumb not trying the zip file....thanks

Comment: I think there is a problem with some of the mirrors. I have the same problem here. Try the US mirror and you will be fine: `install.packages('partykit', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`