# R - Shiny - Where can we find the .tar.gz file of the master version of DT package?

Tags: r, dt

I need to install the version 0.1.40 of the DT package (https://github.com/rstudio/DT) on a Linux server which is not connected to internet. Thus I can't use the statement `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')`.

Thus I need to get the DT_0.1.40.tar.gz file to install this development version of DT.

Where can I find the tar.gz file of the version 0.1.40 of DT ?

Thanks.

Comment: Here: http://yihui.name/xran/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link toward your DT .tar.gz file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fine with the version on CRAN, you can go to `DT`'s [page on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DT/index.html) to download the package tarball. There is a link beside the text "Package source:". Here's the [link](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/DT_0.1.tar.gz) for linux.

However, it looks like you want the development version that is currently not the version found on CRAN. You can actually download the source from github as a tarball using this link:

https://github.com/rstudio/DT/archive/master.tar.gz

then just transfer it to your linux box and [install the package from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source).

```
install.packages("/path/to/master.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Comment: Great help for a non IT specialist person like me! I noted well your links and statement; very helpful. Thank you.