# How to get R library after installing?

Tags: r, package, rstudio, devtools

In RStudio, I installed the package "devtools".

It seems to work, I get the message that "the downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpGgMiD2/downloaded_packages’".

However, then `library(devtools)` does not work.

[image]

How can I make the package available?

Answer (score 2):

If you read your error messages, you'll see that `curl`, one of the dependencies of `httr`, which in turn is one of the dependencies of `devtools` didn't install correctly, hence `devtools` also didn't install.

That's why `library(devtools)` didn't work.

---

To fix this, you could try again with installing `curl` from the downloaded file.  Either call `install.packages` with `repos = NULL` and a path to the downloaded file, or in RStudio click `Install Packages` and choose `Install from:` `Package Archive File (.zip; .tar.gz)`

I can't see from your screenshot, but if installation of the binary version of `curl` doesn't work, you could try [installing the package from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run this command:

```
install.packages('devtools', dependencies = TRUE)
```

This should install the devtools packages but, it will also install all the dependencies (other packages required by the devtools package). After that when you run:

```
library(devtools)
```

You should not have any errors left.