# install.packages ksh error when trying to install shiny package

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, rstudio-server, install.packages

Trying to install Shiny local pacakge after downloading:

```
install.packages("/tmp/shiny_0.13.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

I get this error:

```
-ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected
```

is the syntax right ? Please advise

Comment: did you mean install.packages("shiny") . Shiny is available in cran .

Comment: I tying as per this stackflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source

Comment: If all you have to do is install an R package available on cran , you can do install.packages("packagename") , in this case install.packages("shiny") ...Additionally sometimes I have had to specify the repo name from the list available at : https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html if i sense some problem with the default mirror

Comment: Syntax looks correct to me although the shiny on CRAN is version 0.13.2. What does this return:  `file.exists("/tmp/shiny_0.13.1.tar.gz")`

Comment: `ksh`? I.e., Korn shell?  Did you running this line in the shell?  It needs to be run in an R session.