# Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ROracle’ These will not be installed

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I tried to install `ROracle` package in R. But unable to install the package. It is giving me the following error:

> Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of   C/C++/Fortran: ‘ROracle’
>     These will not be installed

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I also tried installing RTools, but no solution.

Comment: Install RTools and build it from source...

Comment: Did you specify install from source? See answers at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source

Comment: Thanks @nrussell : I tried that way also, but no solution.

Comment: Thanks @ Tom Evans, I even followed that post but it is also not installing the package.

Comment: What does "no solution" mean???

Comment: still giving me the same error message: Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ROracle’ These will not be installed

Comment: 1. Make sure RTools is installed correctly. 2. `install.packages("ROracle", type = "source")`.

Comment: Thanks @nrussell, The mistake is with respective to the improper environment variable setup. Now I was able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I attempted to install the ROracle package from CRAN, I received the same error message. To fix it, I found that I needed to install the ROracle package located on the [Oracle.com website](https://www.oracle.com/index.html). You'll need to sign up a free account first, and then you can find it by searching for "ROracle".

This package can be downloaded and installed error-free. It worked perfectly for me.