# I am trying to install lime: Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘lime’

Tags: r, windows, installation, package

I am using Windows 10.
I am trying to install "lime" and I am getting this error. I looked for a solution already here:

[Error in R: (Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249980/error-in-r-package-which-is-only-available-in-source-form-and-may-need-compil)

and here:

[Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ROracle’ These will not be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327572/package-which-is-only-available-in-source-form-and-may-need-compilation-of-c-c)

I have tried both of these, however it does not seem to be working for me. Do I need to install a C++ compiler, then? Thanks.

Comment: @BaummitAugen this error came up before installation began. I was looking for help here?

Comment: @BaummitAugen and of course I followed the guide. And the two other threads here.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I have tried different mirror sites, and even different versions using remotes and install_version("lime", "0.4.0")

Comment: @BaummitAugen the difference that way was that the installation blew up at the end, but with a similar error message.

Comment: It's not clear if you have installed Rtools. If you have done so, then you should report version numbers for Windoze, R and Rtools and then post the code you are using to install and full copies of any error messages.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Maybe you C++ guys can delete your comments. This is clearly a Q for R users.