# Install devtools-1.12.0.9000

Tags: r, devtools

II would like to install devtools-1.12.0.9000 on my raspberry pi so that I can use install_github on R3.1.1 installed there.
The 9000 patch solves the capabilities("libcurl") problem but I cannot figure out how to install it. Is there somewhere I can download the tar.gz file without using install_github.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [`devtools` project page](https://github.com/hadley/devtools)

Find the download repository link; click to [Download Zip](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/archive/master.zip).

Try the approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source) to install from the tarball.

Alternatively, just install the CRAN version of `devtools`, then use older version of `install_github` included therein to install the new version:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/devtools")
```

Comment: Thanks. I did suggestion 1, downloaded the zip to my pc, moved it to a share on my raspberry pi, and it i

Comment: Installed with no problem using install.packages, repos=NULL,type="source".

Comment: Suggestion 2 doesn't work because of a known bug that Hadley kindly fixed in the 9000 patch.

Comment: @Nguinasso oh, I see. I didn't/don't know what you mean by "the 9000 patch". Could you provide a reference?

Comment: One of the changes in dplyr-1.12.0.9000 is to fix a problem with capabilities("libcurl") in R3.1 which prevents using install_github with R3.1. My raspberry pi loads R3.1.1 so it cannot use dplyr-1.12.0 install_github.