# Trouble installing the update Bipartite package in R 3.3.0?

Tags: r, bipartite

Is any solution to fix the trouble? I am interested in to install the bipartite package from github.`library(devtools)`     `install_github ("carsten/bipartite")` or    `install_github("biometry/bipartite")` or even r bipartite?

Comment: Interested in Bipartite 2.08

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Why don't you install from CRAN? `install.packages("bipartite")`

Comment: @lizzie This is the error I get Downloading GitHub repo carsten/bipartite@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/carsten/bipartite/zipball/master
Error in stop(github_error(request)) : Not Found (404)

Comment: Bipartite 2.08 is not available in CRAN.

Comment: sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Comment: Installing bipartite been a problem for many ecologists I work with. One thing we've found helpful is when dependencies don't load, installing those packages again, and if applicable, selecting `no` when we get this question `Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) `

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to: https://github.com/biometry/bipartite

2) Download the version you want. In this case you want the 2.08. So download the file `bipartite_2.08.tar.gz`.

3) Go to R and use the command

```
install.packages(path_to_file, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

The `path_to_file` is where the downloaded package is. For example, in my case, is in the `Downloads` folder. So, I would do:

```
 install.packages("~/Downloads/bipartite_2.08.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: installing *source* package 'bipartite' ...
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="bipartite.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="bmn5.o identifyModules.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'bipartite'
* removing 'C:/Users/Btc/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/bipartite'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Btc/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/bipartite'

Comment: Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Btc\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" "C:/Users/Btc/Downloads/bipartite_2.08.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("C:/Users/Btc/Downloads/bipartite_2.08.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Btc/Downloads/bipartite_2.08.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source

Comment: library(downloader)
download("https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/archive/master.tar.gz", "rCharts.tar.gz")
install.packages("rCharts.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

Comment: Above code works like a magic even with R 3.3.0? I wish to get such solution, as previous operations were unsuccessful for bipartite.

Comment: Please, any one with solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install those two first.
Hope it works smoothly. I'll try the package today

```
install.packages("fields")
install.packages("sna")
install.packages("~/Downloads/bipartite_2.08.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```