# R -- What exactly does install_github do?

Tags: r, github

never used R before. I need to integrate R into continuous build.

The script I got has the line

`RUN Rscript -e "devtools::install_github('my-repo', auth_token = '"$Github_Token"')"`

I know this command will download the entire repo, but how is the package installed? Is it looking for the .R files, or is it looking for the .rba files?

My goal is to integrate a build process with a CI. I found a way to construct these rba files through a docker container, but these will not be checked into github. I need to make sure the install doesn't require these rba files, then I can move these files somewhere else.

Comment: Take a look at [general instructions for R package installation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Installing-packages). You can think of `install_github` as a wrapper around this base functionality.

Comment: It downloads the source, builds it and installs it using `install.packages` mechanism for source packages (see [here](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/blob/cc971aa7452c0e748d3d2a916c839f15372049bc/install-github.R#L3407), [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.1/topics/install.packages) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `install_github` installs a package the same as any other method of package installation, but automates the download from github for you. The remote repository needs to be an R package, meaning it needs to have at least an `R/` directory containing R code, a `DESCRIPTION` file containing the package metadata, and a `NAMESPACE` file describing the package imports and exports.

For `install_github` to work, it should not inherently require that your `rba` files are present.

For more information on packages, I suggest reading [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html).

Comment: It also requires that one have first installed the `devtools` package.