# When creating a package, how can I make it compatible to older R versions

Tags: r, rtools

I am trying to create my own R package. But after I build it (using R version 3.5.1, Rtools 3.5) and try to install it I get this error:
package ‘path-to-tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1).

Can I somewhere determine which versions of R is compatible? It is a extremely simple one, just a collection of functions.

The code is here:
https://github.com/jacobfredsoee/LCEF

EDIT: Thank you all, this was indeed so simple a solution I feel ashamed. All I needed to do was to add ", repos = NULL" to the install.

Comment: I don't see how this is a question related to compatibility.  But with that said... you need to show us what you actually did because it sounds like you didn't do the build/install process correctly?

Comment: It seems like you do a build and then are probably just trying to do `install.packages("LCEF")` which won't work without adding additional parameters for a local build.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source

Comment: probably unrelated but you should remove the extra code you at the bottom there: https://github.com/jacobfredsoee/LCEF/blob/master/R/dfmanipulation.R

Comment: Try adding `Depends: R (>= 3.1.0)` with the correct R version to  the description file. Also the error message does not neccessarily mean, that it's a version issue, it could also be a misspelled package name or path.

Comment: Thank you @Dason, that was indeed the solution.