# R keeps asking about "installing from sources that need compilation"

Tags: r, repository, cran, install.packages

I am trying to install packages (`devtools`, `plyr` and several others) and keep getting stuck with the same problem, which seems to appear for some packages more often than others

```
 There are binary versions available but the
  source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
processx  2.0.0.1  3.2.1              TRUE
desc        1.1.1  1.2.0             FALSE
callr       1.0.0  3.1.1             FALSE
git2r      0.21.0 0.24.0              TRUE
rcmdcheck   1.2.1  1.3.2             FALSE
usethis     1.1.0  1.4.0             FALSE
devtools   1.13.4  2.0.1             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?
```

OK, well, I honestly have no idea what that means, but chances are 50/50

Whether I choose y or n I end up with:

```
Packages which are only available in source
  form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘ps’ ‘fs’ ‘pkgload’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n:
```

and whether I choose y or n here I end up with

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/zz/mxrvmdvd2j399kfylbspjp4r0000gn/T/Rtmp1OdcyF/downloaded_packages’
```

I am operating on Mac Mojave 10.4.2 
with RStudio 1.1.463

My expected result was for the package to be installed and I could use something like
    library(package) 
to get started with my work.

I am somewhat experienced in working with R and have never encountered this problem until recently? Do I need to update sth? Change a setting?

UPDATE: `ggplot2` and `biomod2` are showing the same issue
UPDATE: seems to be no problem with R (not RStudio) and the R package manager.... why is this the case?

Comment: I encounter this kind of issues because I am stuck with an older R version, dependencies are a mess in R unfortunately as they have to be declared explicitly, and there is binary/source issue on top of it. The way I sort it out is, if I can't install a given package because of dependencies that are only available in source and that I can't get to install successfully, I go to the CRAN page of the package (devtools for you), go archive and download the latest old packages, and install them from file from recent to older until it works.

Comment: It's frustrating not to be able to do it automatically (I'm sure it could be automated) but that works for me. I actually happen to use an older version of devtools for this reason.

Comment: So, you are saying that if I update my R version it should work?

Comment: You should update R to the newest version and install this tool chain: https://github.com/rmacoslib/r-macos-rtools

Comment: Because I have the most current version, so why does this happen?

Comment: You could also just wait. The binaries will probably be available sooner or later. Alternatively, try a different CRAN mirror in case yours is out of sync.

Comment: I'm not saying this, but the current situation (all packages to the latest version) is always the most tested one, in other case you're placing yourself at different points on different package timelines, and R doesn't handle these things well and you can enter dependency hell.

Comment: devtools is a prominent package, so normally on an up to date installation, it "should" work fine or be corrected really quick, I'm using windows though, so our issues are slightly different.

Comment: @Roland: How can I tell if my CRAN-mirror is out of sync?

Comment: By testing with a different mirror. (In RStudio, see Tools --> Global Options --> Packages)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For packages where it says 
needs compilation : TRUE
you would need RTools if you hit "n" on the dialog box.

RTools usually are installed in the C: Drive on Windows.

This question is similar to yours.

[How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

Answer (score 3):

After reading this question/solution plus others, and experimenting with a package update, I wrote the following paragraph in my own instruction (to myself) for updating R packages.  I'm posting it here, because I think it may be helpful to others.  I'm pretty sure it is correct, except that some updates may fail for reasons that have nothing to do with their compilation status.

> On the pop-up, "Do you want to install from source the packages which need compilation?", [No] will ensure that all packages get updated, but not necessarily to their latest versions.  [Yes] should update everything to its latest version, but only if you installed the latest Rtools.  If Rtools is not up to date, then among packages that have not yet been compiled to binaries, [Yes] will successfully update some (or none) and will fail on some (or none).  If any fail, then update.packages() can be run again, selecting [No] to get the latest versions available without updating Rtools.

Comment: another thing worth mentioning is that compilation of many packages can take a lot of time.