# R - How to update xfun function to 0.25

Tags: r, function, installation

I am trying to install 'tidyverse' in Rstudio (version 1.4.1), yet when I install I get an error that says: 'xfun' >= 0.23 is required.

I have tried to update 'xfun', currently version 0.22 using: `update.packages("xfun")` but it doesn't update,  it remains as version 0.22.

Does anyone know how to update to version 0.23?

Thanks!

Comment: try manually deleting xfun from your r library and reinstalling the xfun package.

Comment: Thanks icj. I have tried this, and it installs the 0.22 version each time.  There is another message that says: `There is a binary version available but the source version is later: binary source needs compilation, xfun        0.22       0.25      TRUE`. I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R keeps asking about "installing from sources that need compilation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346839/r-keeps-asking-about-installing-from-sources-that-need-compilation)

Comment: Not the most detailed write up in that answer, but you have essentially the same problem. The "pre-compiled" version is 0.22, but there is a newer one, 0.25, available but as source code only. You need to download and compile it. That isn't hard to do, really you just need to have RTools installed (not a package) and then select the option when prompted.

Comment: Thanks Adam, this post worked for me.