# How to install MVPARTwrap package in R version 3.6.1?

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to install `mvpart` and `MVPARTwrap` packages in R version 3.6.1.
I install on my PC the folder of these two packages in zip version and load them in the relative folder of the package.

When I run the script `library(mvpart)` I get this message:

> ERROR: 'mvpart' package was built before R 3.0.0: please reinstall it."

I try to load this library in the old version of R (version 2.15) and the message is

> in install.packages (mvpart): object 'mvpart' not found".

I do not understand why it is impossible to load this package. Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("mvpart")`?

Comment: `mvpart` and `mvpartwrap` are not in CRAN anymore. They have been archived in december 2014. Installing in an old version might work if you download the source and install it in that way. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474125/3016975) to install from source.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is no more relevant, but I just had to install those libraries so maybe it will still help someone later. I suggest the install from github as it will install dependencies, you need however to be able to compile the source. So here we go :

1. first install rtools if it is not already installed [go here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and follow the instruction
2. update/install devtools if necessary as described [here](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/devtools.html)
3. using this command, it should work now. you may be asked to update some packages, accept all

   ```
   devtools::install_github("cran/mvpart")
   ```