# How to install gpclib?

Tags: r

I get the following trying to install gpclib package in R 3.6.2:

Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘gpclib’
  These will not be installed

I have already installed Rtools.

I tried with the code:

```
install.packages("gpclib")
```

Trying with

```
install.packages("gpclib", type="source")
```

the message is:

> installing *source package 'gpclib' ...
>   ** package 'gpclib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked **
>     using staged installation ** libs *** arch - i386 Warning in   system(cmd) :
>     'make' not found ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gpclib' *
>     removing 'C:/Users/Juan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/gpclib'
>   Warning message: In install.packages("gpclib", type = "source") :
>     installation of package ‘gpclib’ had non-zero exit status*

Comment: Sound like you will need to compile the source then install it after compilation.

Comment: can you show what code you have used when trying to install please

Comment: perhaps useful; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with the code: **install.packages("gpclib")**. Trying with **install.packages("gpclib", type="source")** the message is: *installing *source* package 'gpclib' ...
** package 'gpclib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gpclib'
* removing 'C:/Users/Juan/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/gpclib'
Warning message:
In install.packages("gpclib", type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘gpclib’ had non-zero exit status*

Comment: try `install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/gpclib_1.5-5.tar.gz", type="source", repos = NULL)`

Comment: although the *make not found* does maybe suggest that rtools isnt being found??