# Rmakrdown not using most recent version of package functions to generate github markdown (md) file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-package, roxygen2, r-library

I'm using an `Rmd` to generate github markdown file. When I make changes to the package locally, build from source, then run knit -> knit to github document, the `.md` file generated still uses the previous versions of the package.

Is there something simple I can run to ensure the code in the `Rmd` points to the most recently built version of the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's as simple as [installing from the `.tar.gz` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474125/5783745) generated when the package is built from source. i.e.

```
install.packages("packagename_0.1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

That's it. Now new R sessions (including the one used to knit the `.md` file) will use that installation of the library (rather than the previous one)