# Installing package from source R

Tags: r, installation, package

I have an R package that I would like to install from [here](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~rpribeiro/uba/), and as instructed by the authors, the way we should install it is as follows:

```
install.packages("uba_0.7.7.tar.gz",repos=NULL,dependencies=T)
```

Thsi gives me the following error in R studio:

> Warning: invalid package 'uba_0.7.7.tar.gz'
>   Error: ERROR: no packages specified
>   In R CMD INSTALL
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘uba_0.7.7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

There is a similar question [on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source). I tried doing as such after downloading the .tar.gz file:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/96171/Downloads/uba_0.7.7.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```

But still having an error:

> ERROR: dependency 'Hmisc' is not available for package 'uba'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/96171/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/uba'
>   In R CMD INSTALL
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘C:/Users/96171/Downloads/uba_0.7.7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

However I tried:

```
install.packages("Hmisc")
```

as well as:

```
install.packages("Hmisc", dependencies = T)
```

But both did nothing. It is also important to note that I have RTools installed. The error is still the same:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/96171/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   ERROR: dependency 'Hmisc' is not available for package 'uba'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/96171/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/uba'
>   In R CMD INSTALL
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘C:/Users/96171/Downloads/uba_0.7.7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I also tried installing it from the cmd, It is not giving me the `Hmisc` error.

**sessionInfo()**

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.3 tools_3.5.3
```

I checked the installed packages needed for the intended package and got the following:

```
> "operators" %in% rownames(installed.packages())
[1] TRUE
> "class" %in% rownames(installed.packages())
[1] TRUE
> "fields" %in% rownames(installed.packages())
[1] TRUE
> "ROCR" %in% rownames(installed.packages())
[1] TRUE
> "DmwR" %in% rownames(installed.packages())
[1] FALSE
> "Hmisc" %in% rownames(installed.packages())
[1] FALSE
```

So I have all except `Hmisc`, how can I install it correctly?

Comment: What does your `sessionInfo()` say? Pls do add this here

Comment: From a quick look at the package description and namespace files you may require other packages; I ran `install.packages(c("operators","class", "fields", "ROCR", "DMwR", "Hmisc"))` and then `uba` installed okay. 
 ps your R version is a wee bit old which can cause issues when installing so do make sure the dependencies install correctly

Comment: @user20650 I did install all these packages, but seperately rather than in one command, or does the order in which they are installed matter ?

Comment: @GWD done. Please find them in the last section

Comment: @Hiyam; no that shouldn't matter. Are you sure that they all installed correctly?

Comment: @user20650 Please see the last section of my problem, I updated it. I have all the packages that you clarified installed, except for ```Hmisc``` its not being installed properly

Comment: @Hiyam; it may be that Hmisc will not install due to your version as some of the dependencies / imports require a certain package version (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) -- these may not be available for 3..5.3. Try updating your R version -- we are now at version 3.6.2

Comment: afaik Hmisc requires compilation; what messages do  you get when trying to install the package `install.packages("Hmisc", type = 'source') 
PS: try doing in the RGui not RStudio!

Comment: @GWD I do get a message saying 'Do you want to download Hmisc with its compilation' and I say yes. Also, I have been trying to download Hmisc from RStudio its taking forever, the same thing does not happen in RGui ?

Comment: just have RGui do the installation (from source) for you - will be available in R (and RStudio equally)

Comment: @Hiyam; dont install Hmisc from source use the binaries (this is almost certainly easier for you and will install dependencies as well if you want) -- bt as previously commented you may need to -- and probably should -- upgrade your r version.

Comment: @user20650 Thank you so much for your help both; I answered my question and referenced you. Much appreciated!!

Comment: @GWD Thank you so much for your help both; I answered my question and referenced you. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending about an hour, thanks to @user20650 and @GWD I was able to solve my problem as follows:

- I previously had R 3.5.3, I upgraded to the latest version 3.6.2
- Steps to upgrade R if you already have it: [tutorial 1](https://uvastatlab.github.io/phdplus/installR.html) and [tutorial 2](https://www.r-statistics.com/2015/06/a-step-by-step-screenshots-tutorial-for-upgrading-r-on-windows/)
- After having R 3.6.2, I used `RGui` rather that `RStudio` to install `Hmisc`
- I typed in the GUI console: `install.packages("Hmisc");` it prompts you for a message about compilation, I clicked on **NO**