# R - Can't install 'SDMTools' for R version 3.6.2

Tags: r, installation, sdmtools

I have issues insalling the R packages `SDMTools`.

```
install.packages("SDMTools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/aaa/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘SDMTools’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)
```

I have also tried

```
BiocManager::install(c('SDMTools'), ask=T ) 
Bioconductor version 3.10 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Installing package(s) 'SDMTools'
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: boot, foreign, lattice, MASS, nlme, nnet
Old packages: 'digest', 'mvtnorm'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
n
Warning message:
package ‘SDMTools’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)
```

My session info is below:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readstata13_0.9.2 devtools_2.2.2    usethis_1.5.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3          rstudioapi_0.11     magrittr_1.5        pkgload_1.0.2       R6_2.4.1            rlang_0.4.4        
 [7] fansi_0.4.1         tools_3.6.2         pkgbuild_1.0.6      sessioninfo_1.1.1   cli_2.0.1           withr_2.1.2        
[13] ellipsis_0.3.0      remotes_2.1.1       assertthat_0.2.1    digest_0.6.24       rprojroot_1.3-2     crayon_1.3.4       
[19] processx_3.4.2      BiocManager_1.30.10 callr_3.4.2         fs_1.3.1            ps_1.3.2            curl_4.3           
[25] testthat_2.3.1      memoise_1.1.0       glue_1.3.1          compiler_3.6.2      desc_1.2.0          backports_1.1.5    
[31] prettyunits_1.1.1
```

Any idea on how to install `SDMTools`? I need it to install the package `rblm`.

Thank you

Comment: [It was removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SDMTools/index.html). You can download and install it from the archive or from it's GH repo (if it has one).

Comment: how do you check if an old version is available, and how do you install it? Thank you

Comment: Download one of the versions from CRANs archive in the link above and use the instructions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source) in order to install it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 12):

Try running this script:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_version("SDMTools", "1.1-221")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but i've been having problems with SDMTools recently, and "remotes" didn't worked. I had success with devtools. Just in case if someone is in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed for me what solved the problem was the following code:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_version("SDMTools", "1.1-221")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32648065)

Answer (score -4):

I used the following script and it worked to install SDMtools in R version 3.6.2

install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_version("SDMTools", "1.1-221")

Comment: This is exactly the same as the answer that's already posted