# Installing package webr failed

Tags: r, pie-chart, install.packages, donut-chart

I am having issues installing the 'webr' package in R, which is necessary to use the PieDonut function to make beautiful multi-level pie charts.

I have followed the instructions on this website, which demonstrates how to install the packages and work with it. https://rpubs.com/cardiomoon/398623

However, when installing the package 'webr' it says:

```
Failed to install 'webr' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) package ‘mnormt’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)
```

It is necessary to install it from GitHub because the CRAN version does not include the PieDonut function.

I already tried to search for older versions of the package and made sure that my R version was up to date, however this did not result in any progress.

Does anybody have any suggestions to help me use this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on R 3.6.2, whereas [mnormt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mnormt/index.html) requires R 4.0.0 or higher.

Installing an older version of the package can go from easy to "I want to jump out the window" difficult. If you go to the [package archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mnormt/) you can find a version that will not depend on newer version of R than you have. You can install it [from source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474125/322912) with, if I remember correctly, something along the lines of

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mnormt/mnormt_1.5-7.tar.gz", 
                 repos = NULL, 
                 type = "source")
```

Assuming all its dependencies do not require something you do not have (i.e. R >= 4.0.0), it should work. If not, you would have to install mnormt dependecies by hand as well, as well as any potential dependencies of dependencies. See what I mean by jumping out of the window?

Alternatively, upgrade your R and you avoid these kinds of problems (in 99.9 % of the time).

Comment: Thank you! I only updated my R studio instead of R itself... -.-

Comment: Rstudio should have no influence on this outcome as it's "only" an IDE.