# R 3.6.2 - SDMTools not available

Tags: r, sdmtools

I followed the steps from:

[How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

but unfortunately, it did not work out, and I even tried a couple of different versions available in:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SDMTools/

After running this command:

install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SDMTools/SDMTools_1.1-20.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")

I always got the same error\warning message, and the package was not installed:

- installing *source* package 'SDMTools' ...
  ** package 'SDMTools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'SDMTools'

- removing 'C:/Users/tiago/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/SDMTools'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/tiago/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp40U7mA/downloaded_packages/SDMTools_1.1-20.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0):

You likely need Rtools https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

For R versions 3.6.3 or older, visit https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading from https://www.rforge.net/SDMTools/files/

This worked for me. I successfully installed version 1.1-221 on a Windows machine. However, even though the installation problems were all resolved, I am not sure the package was fully functional. I couldn't get it to make a continuous legend for a plot.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.