# Is there an R function for computing fast Levenshtein distance with threshold (maxDist)

Tags: r, string, levenshtein-distance

I am looking for an R function, which returns the Levenshtein distance of two strings if the Levenshtein distance is less than a threshold, and saves time by not computing Levenshtein distances larger than the threshold. The threshold is given and should be in the range somewhere between 2 and 10. At first, I thought a lot of computing time can be saved by using a threshold, but I'm not so sure about this any more.
I tried using `amatch` from the `stringdist` package with `maxDist` argument, but it does not seem to speed up the algorithm compared to not using the threshold.

Comment: Provide a minimally reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package named `RecordLinkage` which includes `levenshteinSim` and `levenshteinDist` function.

This package is out of date but can be installed with [old versions](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RecordLinkage/) of source files.

Here is levenshteinSim function explanation of RecordLinkage [package manifest;](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/RecordLinkage.pdf)

```
Details
String metrics compute a similarity value in the range [0, 1] for two strings, with 1 denoting the
highest (usually equality) and 0 denoting the lowest degree of similarity. In the context of Record
Linkage, string similarities can improve the discernibility between matches and non-matches.
jarowinkler is an implementation of the algorithm by Jaro and Winkler (see references). For the
meaning of W_1, W_2, W_3 and r see the referenced article. For most applications, the default values
are reasonable.
levenshteinDist returns the Levenshtein distance, which cannot be directly used as a valid string
comparator. levenshteinSim is a similarity function based on the Levenshtein distance, calculated
by 1 −
d(str1,str2)
max(A,B)) , where d is the Levenshtein distance function and A and B are the lenghts of the
strings.
Arguments str1 and str2 are expected to be of type "character".
```

And you can install packages from source files with .tar.gz in that way;

[How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474125/14587041)